# DKIM "default" selector

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

I often see DKIM configuration guides using `default` as the selector. Is this a special selector or it is just a convention to use this if you only have one mail server?

In other words, if I use the selector `default._domainkeys.example.com`, will this entry be used to validate the signature for `morespecific.selector._domainkey.example.com` the absence of an exact match, or will it only match signatures that specific `d=default` as the selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> often see DKIM configuration guides using default as the selector. Is this a special selector

It is not. There is nothing in RFC 4871 that says "default" as selector as a specific meaning.

Instead its section 4.1 introduces selectors as labels in the `_domainkey` zone that way:

> To support multiple concurrent public keys per signing domain, the
>   key namespace is subdivided using "selectors".  For example,
>   selectors might indicate the names of office locations (e.g.,
>   "sanfrancisco", "coolumbeach", and "reykjavik"), the signing date
>   (e.g., "january2005", "february2005", etc.), or even the individual
>   user.
>
> [..]
>
> Periods are allowed in selectors and are component separators.  When
>   keys are retrieved from the DNS, periods in selectors define DNS
>   label boundaries in a manner similar to the conventional use in
>   domain names.  Selector components might be used to combine dates
>   with locations, for example, "march2005.reykjavik".  In a DNS
>   implementation, this can be used to allow delegation of a portion of
>   the selector namespace.

Note this also:

> While some domains may wish to make selector values well known,
>   others will want to take care not to allocate selector names in a way 
>   that allows harvesting of data by outside parties.  For example, if
>   per-user keys are issued, the domain owner will need to make the
>   decision as to whether to associate this selector directly with the
>   user name, or make it some unassociated random value, such as a
>   fingerprint of the public key.

So there is no fallback on some "default" selector, as the resolution process is governed by:

> All DKIM keys are stored in a subdomain named "_domainkey".  Given a
>   DKIM-Signature field with a "d=" tag of "example.com" and an "s=" tag 
>   of "foo.bar", the DNS query will be for "foo.bar._domainkey.example.com".

(but look at section 3.8 for explanations about how a parent can sign its children content).